# How to load svg map files to android

Tags: android, html, svg

I want to load my svg file to android , i can get the svg file but some parts of map only it shows.and also am getting logcat error as "webcoreglue should not happen no rect-based-test nodes found".

my code is here.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {



    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             String url = "http://10.0.2.2:80/file/myfile.html";

            WebView webview = new WebView(this);
            setContentView(webview);

           try {
                webview.loadUrl(url);
            InputStream fin = getAssets().open("url");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[fin.available()];
            fin.read(buffer);
            fin.close();
            webview.loadData(new String(buffer), "text/html", "UTF-8");
           } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
         }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Note SVG is not supported by Android webview until Honeycomb (3.0). If you run something older then you need to try some work arounds (i.e. [SVG JavaScript polyfill](http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/12-02-17/using_svg_on_android_2_x_and_kendo_ui_dataviz.aspx))